# What printer can print large(-ish) images from a car?

Tags: printer, portable

I need a printer that I can keep in my car in the hot summer months, for making copies of important documents such as contracts, that I frequently have to turn in.  I already have a portable scanner which can scan to an SD card, and a SD-to-USB adapter.  So what I would need is probably a printer that:

- Does not use InkJet technology, since ink dries up from the heat in the car.  Technologies I've found that can work: Laser, Dye Sublimation, Thermal Wax Transfer, Direct Thermal, maybe some others?
- Can print at least on at least 4"-wide paper (at least 5" is strongly preferred)
- Can run off of a battery.  Or at least, have a DC input, so I can connect an external battery to it.
- [preferred] Can print off of a USB stick or a memory card, so I don't have to get another scanner.  In general, might be worth mentioning, printing over which of the following it supports: PC, Mac, USB, SD, WiFi, BlueTooth, PictBridge.

Also, things that I don't care about, but might be important for others in this situation, so it might be worth mentioning if you know:

- Can it print in color?
- What paper / ink does it use, to help gauging the cost per page?
- Maximum length of an image it can print.
- Number of seconds it takes to print a single maximum-size picture.
- How frequently does it jam / have other technical issues?

Comment: Have you considered an invertor, that you plug into your cigarette lighter and it gives you a regular outlet?  Yes, the number of amps is less than a regular outlet, but then almost any low powered printer works.

Comment: That would work, but there is no such thing as a low-power laser printer -- since it needs power to burn the toner onto the paper.  (reference: https://forums.anandtech.com/threads/recommend-me-a-low-power-laser-printer.2359188/) And a low-power ink printer would still face the problem of ink drying up in the car.  Feel free to post an answer if you can find a workaround.